# initialization of variable in pre in Modelica

Tags: initialization, pre, modelica

I wrote the codes in Modelica as below:

```
model TestIniitial
  extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
  parameter Integer nWri= 2;
  Real u[nWri](each start= 10, fixed=false);
  Real uPre[nWri];
  parameter Real _uStart[nWri] = fill(10, nWri);
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Time startTime = 0;
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Time samplePeriod = 1;
  Boolean sampleTrigger "True, if sample time instant";
initial equation 
  u[1] = 1;
  u[2] = 2;
equation 
   sampleTrigger = sample(startTime, samplePeriod);

  when sampleTrigger then
    for i in 1: nWri loop
      uPre[i] = pre(u[i]);
    end for;
  end when;

  for i in 1:nWri loop
    u[i] = (i+1)*time;
  end for;

end TestIniitial;
```

Basically I want to initialize the u before simulation. However, I got below complaints(the initialization of u is over-specified) from translation:

```
The Modelica Language Specification 3.2.1 specifies that if a real variable, v,
is appearing in an expression as pre(v), but not assigned by a when equation,
then the equation v = pre(v) should be added to the initialization problem.

For this problem the following equations were added:
u[1] = pre(u[1]);
u[2] = pre(u[2]);
```

I can't understand the complaints since pre(v) was assigned in when equation already. What can I do if I want to initialize the u in above codes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this, my guess is that the error message is trying to provide you some diagnostics but it is incorrect about the source.  I suspect (again, I do not know for sure) that it sees the fact that `pre(u)` appears in the model and that there is an initialization problem and assumes a specific issue.

My guess is that the issue stems from the fact that you have `fixed=true` set on `u`.  I see no reason to do that and my guess is that it will lead to too many constraints on the initialization problem as well.  Get rid of the `fixed=true` and see what happens.  Report back if that doesn't address the problem.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi @Michael Tiller, I did `fixed = flase` for u in my codes. Actually, if I delete the initial equation, the model works well with 0 as the initial value of `u`. However, my intention is to set the initial value of `u` by myself.

Comment: Ah.  I misread the code.  Sorry about that.  If `fixed=false`, then you should be ok.  The fact that you've set `start` using `each` is also the way to go.  I think this is a case where you need to file a ticket with the tool.  It all looks correct to me.

Comment: thanks, Michael, I am going to try OpenModelica first. If not working, I am going to contact Dymola.